# How to get window width in javascript to match the css media?

Tags: javascript, css

In css I have this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {

}
```

what would be the equivalent javascript code to get the same width value that the css uses for @media max-width?

Thanks

Comment: should just be `window.innerWidth`

Comment: @dotconnor Actually `innerWidth`

Comment: do you want to get/set this css property max-width: 860px from your js ?

Comment: no, just find out what the JS width code is that the css uses for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that there is no way to get CSS from JavaScript code without parsing CSS file. JavaScript has a similar method is [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia). Usage:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```